# What is the standard/correct way to load c++/cli dll into c# appdomains?

Tags: c#, dll, appdomain

I need to create a C# application where I can load and unload C++/CLI dlls dynamically, so I am using appdomains.

I'm loading the dll this way (in my appdomain):

```
Assembly assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("dllName");
Type m_configType = assembly.GetType("typeName");
object m_configObject = Activator.CreateInstance(m_configType);
```

I can load the dll and use it as I want, but the thing is that when the code runs the last line of code I copied, the dll is loaded in all of my appdomains.

How can I prevent that behaviour?

Output:

[image: Output]

I'll give you the code of the project to recreate the behaviour:

> AppdomainTest Project - Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  AppDomain appDomain = CreateAppDomain("PluginLoaderDomain");
  PlugIn plugin = InstantiatePlugin("PluginLoader", appDomain);
  Console.WriteLine("Main domain assemblies before loading:");
  PrintLoadedAssemblies();
  plugin.LoadRuntimeAssembly();
  Console.WriteLine("Created appdomain assemblies:");
  plugin.PrintLoadedAssemblies();
  Console.WriteLine("Main domain assemblies after loading:");
  
  PrintLoadedAssemblies();
  Console.WriteLine("Unloading appdomain");
  Console.WriteLine("");
  Console.WriteLine("Main domain assemblies after unloading:");
  AppDomain.Unload(appDomain);
  PrintLoadedAssemblies();
  IsUnloaded(plugin);
}
```

```
static AppDomain CreateAppDomain(string dllName)
{
   AppDomainSetup setup = new AppDomainSetup()
   {
      ApplicationName = dllName,
      ConfigurationFile = dllName + ".dll.config",
      ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
      ShadowCopyDirectories = "true",
      ShadowCopyFiles = "true"
   };
   AppDomain appDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain(setup.ApplicationName, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, setup);

   return appDomain;
}
```

```
static PlugIn InstantiatePlugin(string dllName, AppDomain domain)
{
   PlugIn plugIn = domain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(dllName, dllName + ".PlugIn") as PlugIn;

   return plugIn;
}
```

```
static void IsUnloaded(PlugIn plugin)
{
   bool unloaded = false;

   try
   {
      Console.WriteLine(plugin.Name);
   }
   catch (AppDomainUnloadedException)
   {
      unloaded = true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
   }

   if (unloaded)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Appdomain unloaded.");
   }
   else
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Error! Appdomain not unloaded.");
   }
}
```

> PluginLoader Project - Plugin.cs

```
public class PlugIn : MarshalByRefObject
{
   private string name;

   public string Name { get { return name; } }

   public void Initialize()
   {
      name = "PlugIn 1";
   }

   public void LoadRuntimeAssembly()
   {
      Assembly assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load("dllName");
      Type m_configType = assembly.GetType("typeName");

      object m_configObject = Activator.CreateInstance(m_configType);
   }
}
```

```
public void PrintLoadedAssemblies()
{
   Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
   Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");

   foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName.Substring(0, assembly.FullName.IndexOf(',')));
   }

   Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
   Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/assembly/load-unload)

Comment: The problem here is that the dll loads also in the main appdomain, but it should load only in the one I specifically created

Comment: FWIW, AppDomains are gone with .NET Core (.NET 5 and beyond), and C++/CLI future is uncertain https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/cpp-cli so you might want to rethink your architecture if future is important.